# How to add bookmarks to PDF automatically? (using headings/Toc)

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I have several PDFs which I want to have bookmarks in. I can't read them without those bookmarks.

I simply want to use the headings/TOC as bookmarks, but I don't want to do it manually (there are several pdfs with a lot of headings/pages).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I did this eventually with [Nitro PDF Professional](http://www.nitropdf.com/professional/overview.htm).

There's an option for creating bookmarks using the headings of each chapter / sub chapters.